# EditText automatically sets to uneditable in fragment when scrollview is filled

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a 4 fragments that contain a scrollview and an edit text, and elements are added dynamically to that scroll view in java. If the scrollview is empty I can edit the edittext normally without any problem, but as soon as the scrollview gets an element that same edit text is no longer clickable, on pressing it it is not focusing on it nor is the keyboard opening, any suggestions?

here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/daily"
    tools:context=".Daily">

    <Button
        android:text="ADD"
        android:id="@+id/DADD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/did"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="Enter task ID"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and here is the java code:

```
sv = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        Log.d("daily", "Linear layout created!");
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


        if(check.isEmpty() == true){
            Log.d("daily", "no Tasks Found!");
        }else{
            Log.d("daily", "Found some tasks!");
            for(int i = 0; i<check.size(); i++){
                checka = check.get(i).split(";");
                TaskManager TM = new TaskManager();
                TM.id = Integer.parseInt(checka[0]);
                //Log.d("update", Integer.toString(TM.id));
                //Log.d("update", checka[0]);
                LinearLayout ll2 = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                Log.d("daily", "Linear layout created!");
                ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                Log.d("daily", "string split done!");
                //CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getActivity());
                TM.cb = new CheckBox(getActivity());
                Log.d("daily", "check box created!");
                if(Integer.parseInt(checka[2]) == 1){
                    TM.cb.setChecked(true);
                }
                TM.content = new TextView(getActivity());
                Log.d("daily", "textview created!");
                TM.content.setText(checka[0] + "." + " " + checka[1]);
                tasks.add(TM);
                //Log.d("update", Integer.toString(tasks.get(i).id));
                //Log.d("update", Integer.toString(tasks.get(i).id));
                Log.d("daily", "added text to the text view!");
                ll2.addView(TM.cb);
                //Log.d("daily", "added checkbox to created linear layout!");
                ll2.addView(TM.content);
                Log.d("daily", "added textview to created linear layout!");
                ll.addView(ll2);
            }
            sv.addView(ll);
            Log.d("daily", "added the created linear layout to the scroll view!");
        }
```

Comment: More description could help us more.. Could you please add the Java Code that is adding those new elements to the scroll view?

Comment: java code added